# Actions of Google doesn't play correctly SSML emphasis and consider it as a paragraph

Tags: actions-on-google, ssml

I found that when I'm sending back a response with `<emphasis>` inside of sentence Actions of Google considers it as a new paragraph and breaks the sentance.

For example:

```
<speak>
     <p>
        Do you like <emphasis level="strong">red</emphasis>, <emphasis level="strong">blue</emphasis> or <emphasis level="strong">green</emphasis> car?
     </p>
     <p>
        Do you like red, blue or green car?
    </p>
</speak>
```

[Here is rendered mp3](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uVkXDXl-xzQJmHp4DVJDN13BXkeeOh_B).

This bug could be replicated in `TTS Simulator`. Or sent as a response by official [node.js SDK](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs)

*I have added 2 sentences here and `<p>` to highlight the difference. But, actually, it isn't necessary here. And the problem could be replicated without those tags.*

According to [SSML standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis/#S3.2.2) `<emphasis>` could be in the middle of a sentence.

*In additional. I've tried the same tag on Amazon Alexa and it doesn't consider it as a new line.*

## PS:

More over Actions of Google breaks rendering of speech text and adds an extra newline before/after the `<emphasis>`. But it is the minor problem - because I could fix it by displayText. Broken speech is more important here.

Comment: Thanks for reporting. This is a known issue that we plan to resolve in the future. For now, emphasis will work on the sentence level.

Comment: @LeonNicholls thanks for the support! It is good to know. Can't wait to use this feature in production, btw what about other SSML feature, is there any document of the level of implementation/support?

Comment: Our current support for SSML is documented here: https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml

Comment: @LeonNicholls btw I have found that the same problem we have with `<prosody>` tag

Comment: This is still not resolved as of August 2020. I need to be able add emphasis to individual words in my project! What's the story Google?